# currently generating xml from xlsx. with new xlsx and xsd, how to avoid manually remapping cells?

Tags: excel, xml, xsd

I inherited a 2022.xlsx spreadsheet where I will key in the cell values and generate an xml file via DEVELOPER>EXPORT function and send out the xml to outside party. As you can see in the top pic, when I do a DEVELOPER>SOURCE, the right menu bar displays the mapped cells from 2022.xlsx.

Now there is a new change where new cell data need to be submitted. I am given a 2023.xlsx template and the corresponding 2023.xsd (as show in bottom pic). Now here's the problem I am facing - from these 2 files, the mapping for the cells are all gone. Other than manually re-mapping all the cells individually in 2023.xsd/2023.xlsx, which is painful and onerous (the actual cell layout is much more complex), is there a better way to have the mapping done, or to generate the new xml ? The only files i have are 2022.xlsx (existing file with values input), 2023.xslx (xlsx template based on new layout), 2023.xsd and 2023.xml (sample xml for the new layout)

[image: PIC A]

[image: PIC B]

Comment: To be clear, i am seeking guidance what are the possible options for this?